# Which permissions do Azure AD Apps need to get SPO admin rights?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, azure, azure-automation

I want to automate SharePoint admin tasks with Azure Automation. I don't want to use user/password but Service Principle. (We have MFA enforced.)

I set up a new "Azure Automation" account, including an "Azure Run As" account. I added PnP modules. I assigned the following rights via https://*mytenant*-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/AppInv.aspx

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/Tenant" Right="Manage"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

In my scripts now I can `Connect-PnPOnline` or do some random other stuff, but whenever I want to do privileged things, like `Get-PnPTenantSite` I'm running into errors:

```
Get-PnPTenantSite : Current user is not a tenant administrator.
At line:5 char:1
+ Get-PnPTenantSite
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPTenantSite], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.GetTenantSite
```

How do I give the scripts in Azure Automation full SPO admin rights?

Comment: P.S.: Here's the theory: https://worktogether.tech/2018/06/09/connect-to-sharepoint-online-in-azure-automation-app-credentials/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://medium.com/ng-sp/sharepoint-add-in-permission-xml-cheat-sheet-64b87d8d7600) is a good cheat sheet for app permissions. To grant full access (tenant admin) you would use the following:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
 </AppPermissionRequests>
```

Comment: It works. I marked the question as answered. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it's a new question, but: How does this work cross-tenant?

Comment: You would need to set this up pr tenant

Comment: Understood. Thank you!